# gdaladdo memory issue:

Tags: gdal, memory, gdaladdo

I have a `.gpkg` raster that holds data (only) in zoom level 15.
I then tried to build overviews with `gdaladdo` for this raster, using the following command:
`gdaladdo --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1500 --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW DEFLATE -r bilinear DUMMY.gpkg 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384 32768`

It DOES manage to build overviews until a certain point (zoom level 11), where it fails with this message:
`0...10...20..ERROR 2: overview.cpp, 4145: cannot allocate 29949646468 bytes`

One more thing is, when I run gdaladdo on this raster without any parameters (e.g. `gdaladdo -r bilinear DUMMY.gpkg`) - it SUCCESSFULLY builds the overviews BUT the process ends in zoom level 10 (if fills zoom levels 10-14).

Tested on two machines with `GDAL 3.2.0` and `GDAL 3.3.0` and got the same results.

Comment: I have never tried tried to store large rasters in gpkg, I prefer tif. If you don't necessarily need the gpkg, try with a bigtif. Alternatively, you could use an external pyramid in tif with -ro (and --config BIGTIFF_OVERVIEW YES )

Comment: `gpkg` is necessary for my needs :) thanks

Comment: It's a known issue: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6619 You are retrieving a lot of pixels in one step so they can be compressed.

Comment: @vinh I build the overviews in steps so lower zoom levels are built first. Seems that without specifying levels, GDAL doesn't produce low zoom levels. Is there any alternative?

Comment: The trac ticket suggest that if you start with a working compression level and do a few more it should work, so maybe try level 2 4 8 16 then 16 32 64 128 and so on.